# MLE for $\theta>0$ with $(X_1,\dots,X_n)\sim \mathcal N(\theta, 2\theta)$

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, maximum-likelihood

I want to determine the MLE for $\theta$ given a sample $(X_1,\dots, X_n)\sim \mathcal N(\theta, 2\theta)$. I know that the likelihood function is $$f(X;\theta) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt\theta}\prod_{i=1}^n\exp\left(-\frac{(X_i-\theta)^2}{4\theta}\right).$$
The log likelihood function is therefore $$L(X;\theta) = -\log(2\sqrt\theta) -\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i-\theta)^2}{4\theta}.$$
If we differentiate and solve $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = -\frac{1}{2\theta} - \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{X_i^2}{4\theta^2}+\frac{1}{4}\right]\\$ we get
\begin{align*}
        0 &= -\frac{1}{2\theta} -\sum_{i=1}^n \left[\frac{X_i^2}{4\theta^2}+\frac 1 4\right]\\
    \iff 0 &= 2\theta - \sum_{i=1}^n[X_i^2+\theta^2]\\
    \iff 0 &= -n\theta^2 + 2\theta - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\\
    \iff 0 &= \theta^2 -\frac{2}{n}\theta + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2
\end{align*}
Which is $0$ if $\theta_{1,2} = \frac 1 n \pm\sqrt{\frac 1 {n^2} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2}$. But this is highly implausible because the square root term is most likely negative. From experimentations in Python I can say that $$\theta^\ast = \frac 1 n + \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2} + \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)}$$ seems to work quite well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you are solving $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\theta}=0$ (and not maximizing it), you get $\hat\theta=\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i^2}$. But note that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i^2\ne \bar X^2$. When you have this $\hat\theta$, it *is* the MLE, no limit to compute. You have $\frac{n}{4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{4}$ in $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\theta}$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut oh yes it is $\overline{X^2}$ and not $\overline{X}^2$. I will have another look tomorrow.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left[\frac{X_i^2}{4\theta}-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\theta}{4}\right] = \frac{X_i^2}{4\theta^2}+\frac{1}{4}$ right? Where do you get $\frac n 4$?

Comment: $1/4$ appears when you expand the summand, so the sum runs on it too. For $X_i^2$ you get $\sum_i X_i^2$, but a constant is multiplied by the number of terms, so $n/4$. A common mistake when I was in university, if I remember well.

Comment: Yes but I multiply by $4\theta$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{4}$ becomes $n\theta^2$ as I have it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I finally got what you mean. But you have to add parens around the summand, otherwise it's absolutely not clear that it's still inside the summation. As is, it reads as if it were out.